# Add a name badge to a cursor in VSCode extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio Code extension that should replicate Microsoft's Live Share extension.
One of the features that I would like to replicate from their extension is the "name badge" that appear on the cursor.

[For instance, "Amanda Silver" is the "name badge"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo88p.png)

How can I replicate it?